# Solving a modified numerical heat equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, linear-programming, heat-equation

I'm having a bit of trouble finding a good numerical form for this modified version of the heat/diffusion equation and I was just wondering if I am tackling this question the correct way. Firstly, I have a type of heat equation defined by the equation:

$\frac{\partial V}{\partial t} + \frac{\sigma^2}{2} \gamma = 0$

where $\gamma = S^2 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial S^2} $

For this type of equation it is fairly straightforward to find a numerical scheme. However, I now have a modified version of this equation as follows:

$\frac{\partial V}{\partial t} + \frac{\sigma^2}{2} \frac{\gamma}{1-\lambda\gamma} = 0$

where $\lambda\gamma < 1$ and $1 - \lambda\gamma > 0$.

When I try finding a numerical form of this equation I now run into quite a bit of trouble. I am trying to create a numerical implicit scheme and I am following the method outlined on page 9 of this document: http://www.math.uaic.ro/~annalsmath/pdf-uri%20anale/F1(2010)/Mosneagu.pdf
and on page 24 of this document: http://www.ehu.eus/aitor/irakas/fin/apuntes/pde.pdf

Following these methods, the different values in the equation above have numerical forms as follows:

$\frac{\partial V}{\partial t} = \frac{v^{m+1}_{n} - v^{m+1}_{n}}{\Delta t}$

$(\Delta S)^2\frac{\partial V^2}{\partial S^2} = \frac{v^{m+1}_{n+1} - 2v^{m+1}_{n} + v^{m+1}_{n-1}}{(\Delta S)^2}$

When I now plug these terms into equation above and solve for $v^{m}_{n}$ I get:

$v^{m}_{n} = v^{m+1}_{n} + \frac{\sigma^2\Delta t}{2}\large[\frac{v^{m+1}_{n+1} - 2v^{m+1}_{n} + v^{m+1}_{n-1}}{1-\lambda(v^{m+1}_{n+1} - 2v^{m+1}_{n} + v^{m+1}_{n-1})}\large]$

The problem I find however is that I don't know how to put this into a matrix equation to solve for all the terms  - each time I've tried to rearrange the equation suitably I can't seem to isolate each $v$ term. In fact, the only 'good' way to solve this equation numerically which I can think of is to instead observe that in the equation
$\frac{\partial V}{\partial t} + \frac{\sigma^2}{2} \frac{\gamma}{1-\lambda\gamma} = 0$

we treat the $1-\lambda\gamma$ denominator as a 'constant' type of value and write the $\gamma$ in the numerator as $\gamma = (\Delta S)^2\frac{\partial V^2}{\partial S^2} = \frac{v^{m+1}_{n+1} - 2v^{m+1}_{n} + v^{m+1}_{n-1}}{(\Delta S)^2} $ so that we can solve it in a similar numerical manner as the first equation mentioned.  I'm quite new to computational mathematics so I know this might be easy, but if someone can help me out with this I'd really appreciate it, thanks in advance.

Edit: I should also note that I've tried to modify the fraction into a 'neater' form (such as through partial fractions or something) but it didn't work out naturally since the terms are in the denominator.

Comment: Because the PDE is nonlinear, an implicit method will require solution of a nonlinear system of equations.

Comment: I see, could you give me an idea on how I should tackle this problem? This might sound weird but I'm actually from a probability background, this is quite literally only the 2nd week I've started looking into PDE and numerical PDE models (I only finished learning how to program an implicit scheme 3 days ago!). So I really have no idea how to do this...

Comment: TBH I'd just use an explicit scheme, and maybe do a predictor-corrector step to improve things. You do have to worry about stability though. Another option, that can work well is to do your own spatial discretisation to effectively give you a system of ODE's for the time derivative at each spatial grid point. Then you can use a Runge-Kutta method, or whatever really, to do the time-stepping.

Comment: Ah okay thanks for that, I'll look into those methods now then

Comment: Sorry, I'm having a bit of trouble finding how to use a spatial discretization to give a system of ODE's. Do you happen to have any resources which show how to do this, or (if it's not too much trouble) could you show me how to do it for this equation?

Comment: Just write $$\frac{\partial V_{n}}{\partial t}=\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\left[\frac{v_{n+1} - 2v_{n} + v_{n-1}}{1-\lambda(v_{n+1} - 2v_{n} + v_{n-1})}\right],$$ which gives you an equation for each grid point, and use any old time-stepping method. You do have to be careful with stability. It is a very simple method to implement.

Comment: Maybe it should be $-\sigma^2/2$...

Comment: But how do I set it up into a matrix? The numerical heat equation has a tridiagonal matrix, but I can't seem to get a tridiagonal matrix for this equation...

Comment: You wont be able to get a matrix problem, because the equation is non-linear.

Comment: I see :/ If I were to go about solving this numerically, what would I have to do? I'm sorry for all the stupid questions, I've never done any of this before

Comment: Start of by learning a little about time-stepping. Look up Euler's method, the improved Euler method, and Runge-Kutta methods. There are plenty of resource on the internet and on this site to help with that.

Comment: OH! I didn't see that in the new equation you wrote you removed the 'm' values on all the v terms, I think I know what you mean now. Thanks heaps, I'll check that out